# text slider using csss

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I have a simple 3 text I want to add slide down effect of these text here is what I have so far jsfiddle [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/cd8nzbLr/)

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', 'sans-serif';
  color: #cecece;
  background: #222;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.item-1,
.item-2,
.item-3 {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 2em;
  width: 60%;
  font-size: 2em;
  animation-duration: 20s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.item-1 {
  animation-name: anim-1;
}

.item-2 {
  animation-name: anim-2;
}

.item-3 {
  animation-name: anim-3;
}

@keyframes anim-1 {
  0%,
  8.3% {
    left: -100%;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  8.3%,
  25% {
    left: 25%;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  33.33%,
  100% {
    left: 110%;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes anim-2 {
  0%,
  33.33% {
    left: -100%;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  41.63%,
  58.29% {
    left: 25%;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  66.66%,
  100% {
    left: 110%;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes anim-3 {
  0%,
  66.66% {
    left: -100%;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  74.96%,
  91.62% {
    left: 25%;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    left: 110%;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<p class="item-1">Fast.</p>

<p class="item-2">Slow</p>

<p class="item-3">Much slow</p>
```

I have a simple 3 text I want to add slide down effect of these text here is what I have so far jsfiddle 
The result I want can be seen in this page if you look at the title named video made [sample](https://videommerce.com/)

For now it just slides right, I want a slide down effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace left with top?

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', 'sans-serif';
  color: #cecece;
  background: #222;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.item-1,
.item-2,
.item-3 {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 2em;
  width: 60%;
  font-size: 2em;
  animation-duration: 20s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.item-1 {
  animation-name: anim-1;
}

.item-2 {
  animation-name: anim-2;
}

.item-3 {
  animation-name: anim-3;
}

@keyframes anim-1 {
  0%,
  8.3% {
    top: -100%;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  8.3%,
  25% {
    top: 25%;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  33.33%,
  100% {
    top: 110%;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes anim-2 {
  0%,
  33.33% {
    top: -100%;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  41.63%,
  58.29% {
    top: 25%;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  66.66%,
  100% {
    top: 110%;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes anim-3 {
  0%,
  66.66% {
    top: -100%;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  74.96%,
  91.62% {
    top: 25%;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    top: 110%;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<p class="item-1">Fast.</p>

<p class="item-2">Slow</p>

<p class="item-3">Much slow</p>
```